# Kotlin AAR library w/ proguard: How to keep ONLY class and method names?

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard, android-library, aar

I am building an android library (aar file) with Kotlin. I need to obfuscate the code in a way that the 3rd party user will see the class and method names, he must be able to use them (they are pubilc), but I need to hide/obfuscate the code itself. 
I tried using this file for the myLibrary\proguard-rules.pro file:
https://github.com/mohitrajput987/android-utility/blob/master/preference/proguard-rules.pro

but every class, method and var is changed, except for a directory that has both a Kotlin and a Java class in it, both files and directory name remained the same.

If this is what I am looking for, what must be changed for Kotlin?

Perhaps something else is wrong?

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

Comment: So in other words you want to keep only the class name and every function inside should be obfuscated?

Comment: yes so he can call the function, see it's name, the arguments it gets and returns, see description, but not see how it works

Comment: Can't validate that it will work, but you can try using this:
`-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <methods>;
}`

But really I can't see a reason why you want to obfuscate the method's body only. In my opinion users should be able to see library's code so if nothing is not working as it should can file bug reports and etc.

Comment: @h4rd4r7c0r3 that worked , thank you.

Comment: @h4rd4r7c0r3 some libraries contain sensitive code like payments which is required by Payment Card Industry (PCI) standards to be obfuscated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone else struggle with this issue, this should do the trick in most cases (when not trying to obfuscate native methods):

```
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
     public <methods>; 
}
```

More about different `keep` options can be found here: [Proguard keep rules](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/usage)